# Clicking on a "report" or an "image-report" using RSelenium

Tags: r, image, selenium, xpath, rselenium

I'm trying to click on an "image" but that image is classified as an "image report" or a "report". HTML code is messy:

```
<report _ngcontent-ifc-c23="" class="dash-inner fill-parent ng-star-inserted dashlet-small-horiz dashlet-small-vert" ng-responsive="" _nghost-ifc-c28="" style="margin-top: 0rem;">
<image-report _ngcontent-ifc-c28="" _nghost-ifc-c39="" class="ng-star-inserted">
<img _ngcontent-ifc-c39="" class="fill-parent" tabindex="-1" src="/SMIWeb/rest/v1/contents/image?imagePath=%2Fshared%2FImages%2FBTN-TaskDetails_ON.png" alt="Image" style="touch-action: none; user-select: none; -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);">
</image-report>
</report>
```

I've tried the following:

```
remDr$findElement(using="xpath", value="//img[@src='/SMIWeb/rest/v1/contents/image?imagePath=%2Fshared%2FImages%2FBTN-TaskDetails_ON.png']")

remDr$findElement(using="xpath", value="//report[@class='dash-inner.fill-parent.ng-star-inserted.dashlet-small-horiz dashlet-small-vert']")

remDr$findElement(using="xpath", value="//img-report[@class='ng-star-inserted']")

remDr$findElement(using="xpath", value="//img[@class='ng-star-inserted']")

remDr$findElement(using="xpath", value="//img[@class='fill-parent']")
```

How do you call an tagname of type "report" or "image-report"?  Answers in any programming language would be helpful (e.g., regular Selenium).

Comment: Provide the link...

Comment: It was a proprietary website that required a login, otherwise I would have!  I resolved the issue (the image was located in a frame).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem ended up being that the image that I wanted to click on was located in a frame.

I accessed the frame using:

```
webElem <- remDr$findElements("css", "iframe")
remDr$switchToFrame(webElem[[1]])
```

Once I switched into the frame, I was able to access the image using the first line of code:

```
details <- remDr$findElement(using="xpath", value="//img[@src='/SMIWeb/rest/v1/contents/image?imagePath=%2Fshared%2FImages%2FBTN-TaskDetails_OFF.png']")
details$clickElement()
```

Also, "image-report" and "report" were both custom elements.

Answer (score 0):

You could give this a try

```
"//img[@class='fill-parent']/.."
```

With this path, you are getting the parent element of the img element

Of course, if your image-report is unique, you could just locate it with:

```
//image-report[@class='ng-star-inserted']
```